# Google API Key for MVC C# Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api-3

What key type should I use from Google Dev Console for an MVC C# Class, when I try to make a Web Request Call?

"**Key for browser applications**" or "**Key for server applications**"?

MVC C# Code:

```
string url = @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?key=" + key + "&origins=" + origin + "&destinations=" + destinations + "&mode=driving&sensor=false&language=pt-PT";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responsereader = sreader.ReadToEnd();
response.Close();

XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.LoadXml(responsereader);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using key for server applications.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But if I have more then one MVC application in the same server IP, can I use different Keys to get independent quota?

Comment: @Patrick In the header of the google dev console you should have a drop-down with your project selected.  You can click on that and create a new project so quotas are kept separate.

Comment: And Google accept requests from the same IP in that case but considere that they are separated? how can they be sure that I'm not changing the key after the quota request has been exceded in the same application?

Comment: Yes, the quotas are tied to the project.

Comment: And how do they technically detect the diference in the HttpWebRequest?

Comment: Based on the key that you send.

Answer (score 1):

You have developer keys and production keys, in development using developer keys and in production use production keys